# Sending bitcoin unconfirmed, now wallet balance is unconfirmed

Tags: multibit, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I am using Multibit HD 0.4.1. I was trying to send 0.5 bitcoin, but it seems to be [unconfirmed](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/84f0d933dd556f75091caa34f5fb8d4a2c0bd75611da09a8c4ae07e228ecccbb) for an hour.
I tried repairing my wallet, thinking that was the issue, but now my previous balance became unconfirmed! I had about $340 in my balance but now it says $0, with $340 unconfirmed. Will the balance be confirmed once the sending transaction is confirmed? This is time sensitive, so I need to resolve this issue quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The other guy is wrong, I have the same problem as you( http://prntscr.com/cv38x1 - the coins were confirmed in 2015 but it shows transaction status as unknown).
Your issue is most likely the one described below:
https://github.com/keepkey/multibit-hd/issues/862
- this didn't work for me, but I recommend you try it as it did help some other people.

Now if you still have the problem, I figured out how to recover around $100 out of $146 by using the Mnemonic phrase to generate my old private keys, but for some reason it only generated some of them (I suspect that the reason I couldn't recover all of them is due to an issue with BIP32 compatibility Multibit had a year ago).

Comment: Please note that Stack Exchange's aim is to provide open Question & Answer pages that help the whole community, for free. Therefore it is not allowed to offer off-site help e.g. by asking to contact you by email. Of course advertising non-free help is not allowed either.

Comment: Keep clicking 'receive' to generate the next addresses that you received the coins on, then you will see your balance on those addresses. Multibit only generates 1 address at a time. If you received coins on an address from 10 addresses in the future, then you won't see it until you click 'receive' 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Having an unconfirmed balance simply means that that wallet is involved in an unconfirmed transaction. This can be a transaction made by that wallet or a transaction by a different wallet which pays to that wallet. Your wallet's balance will be confirmed once every transaction its involved in is confirmed.

Currently, there are more unconfirmed transactions than usual. You can check how many unconfirmed transactions there currently are by clicking [this link](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions). That's why your transaction didn't go through yet even though its fee is high enough.

Repairing your wallet will not make the transaction go through faster. This only depends on when a miner decides to include your transaction in a block. And as I already said, your wallet's balance being unconfirmed simply means that your wallet is involved in an unconfirmed transaction.

Comment: The unconfirmed balance is showing up even when there are no pending transactions.